# Node Js code to connect to kerberos autehnticated mongo server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kerberos

I am trying to connect to Mongo DB server which is Kerberos authenticated in Node JS. I have the key tab file and the krb5 file. Also teh Principal name , server url and service name. Have installed kerberos in Node JS. The below code I am using, but where do i mention to put my keytab file and KRB5 conf file.

Code :

```
     var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
          f = require('util').format,
         assert = require('assert');

         var server = "kerberos.example.com";
         var principal = "drivers@KERBEROS.EXAMPLE.COM";
         var urlEncodedPrincipal = encodeURIComponent(principal);

         MongoClient.connect(format("mongodb://%s@%s/kerberos?authMechanism=GSSAPI&gssapiServiceName=mongodb", urlEncodedPrincipal, server),  function(err, db) {
         assert.equal(null, err);
         db.close();
         test.done();
         });
```

Comment: Not received the solution yet can anyone please look into it.

Comment: Hello, you can refer below url for help, here I am connecting to kerberized apache phoenix using JDBC package on node,js, you can try with mongodb jdbc.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676107/node-js-and-npm-jdbc-package-issue-with-kerberized-apache-phoenix