# node.js and npm jdbc package issue with kerberized apache phoenix

Tags: node.js, jdbc, npm, kerberos, apache-phoenix

I am using nodejs and the npm jdbc package to connect to kerberized Apache phoenix on hortonworks, I am able to connect to non kerberized phoenix with nodejs and jdbc package, but facing below Kerberos authentication error with kerberized phoenix. if anybody has done anything similar, please give some direction.

Klist command:

```
klist -k -t -e /etc/security/keytabs/kafka.headless.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/security/keytabs/kafka.headless.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   1 09/30/16 10:10:27 kafka@REALM.LAN (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = require('http').Server(app);
var https =require('http');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var JDBC = require('jdbc');
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');
var asyncjs = require('async');
//var Pool = require('jdbc/lib/pool');
//var nodeunit = require('nodeunit');
//var _ = require('lodash');

var _ = require('underscore');
 //ar cors = require("cors");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/view'));


server.listen(3000);
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');});

if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
  jinst.setupClasspath(['/etc/krb5.conf',
                         '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hadoop/conf',
                         '/etc/hbase/conf/core-site.xml',
                         '/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml',
                         '/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-policy.xml',
                         '/etc/hbase/conf/hbase_client_jaas.conf',
                         '/etc/hbase/conf/hbase_regionserver_jaas.conf',
                         '/etc/hbase/conf/hdfs-site.xml',
                         '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar',
                         '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar',
                         '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar',
                         '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar',
                         '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/phoenix-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258-thin-client.jar',
                         '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/phoenix-server-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258-runnable.jar',
                         '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/phoenix/phoenix-4.4.0.2.4.2.0-258-client.jar']);


var config = {
  url: 'jdbc:phoenix:piv-prd-os-646.forsys.lan:2181:/hbase-secure:kafka@FORSYS.LAN:/etc/security/keytabs/kafka.headless.keytab',
  drivername: 'org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver',
  //user : 'root',
  //password: 'root',
  //properties: {}
  minpoolsize: 2,
  maxpoolsize: 3
  };

var hsqldb = new JDBC(config);

hsqldb.initialize(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("---- initialize successfully ----")
  }
});
```

Exception:

```
error:  Error: Error running static method
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:395)
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:287)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$300(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:170)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1840)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1819)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1819)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:180)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:132)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:151)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Login failure for kafka@FORSYS.LAN from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/kafka.headless.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:976)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.login(User.java:386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.login(User.java:253)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:282)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:856)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:719)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:584)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:967)
        ... 18 more
```

Comment: Inside the same directory that the keytab exists on your server, please run the following command, then re-edit your question with the results: klist -k -t -e "filename of keytab"

Comment: Side note: why do you put `/etc/krb5.conf` in your CLASSPATH??? Kerberos was created long before Java; its default config file name can be overriden with an env variable (i.e. `KRB5_CONFIG`) but the Java CLASSPATH makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @T-Heron & Samson Scharfrichter, I tried that klist option keytab is generated and is active, I get rid of the login exception when i comment '/etc/krb5.conf' & '/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hadoop/conf' but the new exception comes as Fri Apr 28 13:28:51 CEST 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1493378882538, pause=100, retries=35}, org                       .apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException:                        Broken pipe

Comment: @T-Heron question updated with klist output..

Comment: In the Directory service associated with the Kerberos realm FORSYS.LAN, there is an account named *kafka*.  Check it out, and please ensure it is configured to support AES 256 bit encryption types.  If this is Active Directory, it's found on the Account tab, scroll to the bottom.

Comment: @T-Heron yes entry is there for kafka , we r running other jobs using this user without any issues.

Comment: Is your realm name FORSYS.LAN or is it REALM.LAN?  Please take the opportunity to make your post consistent and then I can delete this comment to protect the name.

Comment: @T-Heron its forsys.lan, I changed it to realm.lan in question as forsys is client name :) (confidential)

Comment: OK.  Question, I'm unfamiliar with Apache Phoenix on Hortonworks, so forgive this next question.  What service is consuming the Kerberos ticket?  Is it HTTP, or some other?

Comment: @T-Heron its not http

Comment: Guys, Finally the issue have been resolved :) , I am updating a question with the solution. Thank You very much for you help.

Comment: @halfer Done, moved to answer box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by below changes:

Solution:

```
if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
  jinst.addOption("-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/user/jar/hbase_client_jaas.conf");
  jinst.addOption("-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf");
  jinst.addOption("-Dkerberos.client.reference.name=Client");
  jinst.setupClasspath([
                        '/etc/hbase/2.4.2.0-258/0/',
                        '/etc/hadoop/2.4.2.0-258/0/',
                        '/home/user/jar/phoenix-4.4.0-HBase-1.1-client.jar'
                         ]);
}

var config = {
 url: 'jdbc:phoenix:ZK1,ZK2,ZK3:2181:/hbase-secure:user@REAL.LAN:/home/user/user.headless.keytab',
 drivername: 'org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver',
  user : 'hbase',
  password: 'hbase'
  };
```